# How to get all key and values from nested JSON in java

Tags: java, json, selenium, hashmap

Hi I need to read all key, values from nested JSON, where ever there is inner JSON. I need that values ignoring the key.From below JSON i need Key values for nested JSON, like: responseStatus-passed,  "statusCode":"200", "retrieveQuoteResponse":null,"quoteGuid":null, etc.ignoring the start key value like: responsePreamble, quoteProductList which has a nested json inside it.

```
{
    "responsePreamble": {
        "responseStatus": "Passed",
        "statusCode": "200",
        "responseMessage": "Records Found"
    },
    "retrieveQuoteResponse": null,
    "totalQuoteProductCount": 2,
    "quoteProductList": {
        "quoteGuid": null,
        "quantity": 180
}
```

Code:

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Map.class); 
Map<String, Map<String, String>> employeeMap = reader.readValue(jsonObject); 
for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> empMap : employeeMap.entrySet()) { 
    Map<String, String> addMap = empMap.getValue(); 
    if(addMap!=null) { 
        for (Entry<String, String> addressSet : addMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(addressSet.getKey() + " :: " + addressSet.getValue()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

OutPut:

```
responseStatus :: Passed
statusCode :: 200
responseMessage :: Records Found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at com.im.api.tests.CompareTwoJsons.main(CompareTwoJsons.java:78)
```

Comment: Can there be more than two nested levels? I mean, is it possible that one nested object, for example "responsePreamble" can contain one more nested object, and that nested object can contain another nested object, etc.

Comment: Hi  Nemanja, Yeas nested object can be dynamic. it might come as nested array of object. like  quoteProductList can contain another nested object. can you please help on that.

Comment: {
  "responsePreamble":{
    "responseStatus":"Passed"
  },
  "quoteHeader":{
    "quoteNumber":"QUO-12518663-T0B3T3",
    "accountInfo":{
      "id":"631b3d5b-62c8-e711-80f3-3863bb343ba0"
    },
    "account":"40114570",
    "contactInfo":{
      "id":"1af63ebb-2680-eb11-a812-000d3a4e381d"
    },
    "contact":"Kenny Tokuda",
    "currencyInfo":{
      "id":"8c27712e-3ba9-e711-80ef-3863bb343ba0",
      "symbol":"$"
    },
    "vendorCurrencyInfo":{
      "id":null
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, the following code will do the job:

```
 String json = "{\n" +
            "   \"responsePreamble\":{\n" +
            "      \"responseStatus\":\"Passed\",\n" +
            "      \"statusCode\":\"200\",\n" +
            "      \"responseMessage\":\"Records Found\",\n" +
            "      \"accountInfo\":{\n" +
            "         \"id\":\"631b3d5b-62c8-e711-80f3-3863bb343ba0\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"account\":\"40114570\",\n" +
            "      \"contactInfo\":{\n" +
            "         \"id\":\"1af63ebb-2680-eb11-a812-000d3a4e381d\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"contact\":\"Kenny Tokuda\",\n" +
            "      \"currencyInfo\":{\n" +
            "         \"id\":\"8c2ef-\",\n" +
            "         \"symbol\":\"$\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"vendorCurrencyInfo\":{\n" +
            "         \"id\":null\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   \"retrieveQuoteResponse\":null,\n" +
            "   \"totalQuoteProductCount\":2,\n" +
            "   \"quoteProductList\":{\n" +
            "      \"quoteGuid\":null,\n" +
            "      \"quantity\":180\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonNode.fieldNames();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        printRec(jsonNode, key);
    }
```

Here is how function `printRec` looks like:

```
public static void printRec(JsonNode jsonNode, String key) {
        JsonNode node = jsonNode.get(key);
        if (node.isObject()) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = node.fields();
            fields.forEachRemaining(field -> {
                printRec(node, field.getKey());
                if (!field.getValue().isObject()) {
                    System.out.println(field.getKey() + " : " + field.getValue());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

When you run this code you should see the following output:

```
responseStatus : "Passed"
statusCode : "200"
responseMessage : "Records Found"
id : "631b3d5b-62c8-e711-80f3-3863bb343ba0"
account : "40114570"
id : "1af63ebb-2680-eb11-a812-000d3a4e381d"
contact : "Kenny Tokuda"
id : "8c2ef-"
symbol : "$"
id : null
quoteGuid : null
quantity : 180
```

Comment: And where there is nested Json object in another object i am getting output like this. responseStatus "Passed"
quoteNumber "QUO-T0B3T3"
accountInfo {"id":"631b3d5b-62c8-e711-80f3-3863bb343ba0"}
account "40114570"
contactInfo {"id":"1af63ebb-2680-eb11-a812-000d3a4e381d"}
contact "Kenny Tokuda"
currencyInfo {"id":"8c2ef-","symbol":"$"}
vendorCurrencyInfo {"id":null}

Comment: @NiharArisal I updated my answer. It should work as expected

Comment: Thank you Nemanja. it's working. i modified a little bit to accomodate other attributes .

Comment: Hi Nemanja, is there anyway to fetch key-values including from json arrays also. for eg: this one.{
  "relatedquoteresponse":{
    "responsepreamble":{
      "responseStatus":"Passed",
      "statusCode":"200"
    },
    "phone":null,
    "symbol":"$",
    "retrieverelatedquotes":[
      {
        "quoteId":23232
      },
      {
        "quoteName":"Netally-Service"
      }
    ],
    "CheckStatus":{
      "StatusCode":200,
      "responseMessage":"Found"
    }
  }
}            getting like this  retrieverelatedquotes : [{"quoteId":23232},{"quoteName":"Netally-Service"}]